# how to call json on local folder

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

How do I call a local JSON file using javascript and php?...
I tried this one but it has an error. I hope you can help me about this

```
<html>
<head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jput-2.js"></script>
        <script src="jput-2.prod.js"></script>
        <script src="jput.min.js"></script>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var json = JSON.parse('ticket.json');
//while running this code the template will be appended in your div with json data
$("#tbody").jPut({
    jsonData:json,
    //ajax_url:"youfile.json",  if you want to call from a json file
    name:"tbody_template",
});

});
</script>   

    </head>
    <body>



<div jput="tbody_template">
 <tr>
  <td>{{ticket:id}}</td>
  <td>{{score}}</td>
 </tr>
</div>

<table>
 <tbody id="tbody">
 </tbody>
</table>


    </body>
</html>
```

and there' an error showing at the console

[image]

Here's my json code:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 21821290968,
        "url": "https://51talk.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/21821290968.json",
        "name": "Rovi Roy Cruz",
        "email": "rovi.cruz@51talk.com",
        "created_at": "2017-04-26T09:55:33Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-23T02:10:22Z",
        "time_zone": "Beijing",
        "phone": null,
        "shared_phone_number": null,
        "photo": null,
        "locale_id": 1,
        "locale": "en-US",
        "organization_id": null,
        "role": "admin",
        "verified": true,
        "external_id": null,
        "tags": [],
        "alias": "",
        "active": true,
        "shared": false,
        "shared_agent": false,
        "last_login_at": "2017-06-23T02:10:22Z",
        "two_factor_auth_enabled": null,
        "signature": "",
        "details": "",
        "notes": "",
        "custom_role_id": null,
        "moderator": true,
        "ticket_restriction": null,
        "only_private_comments": false,
        "restricted_agent": false,
        "suspended": false,
        "chat_only": false,
        "default_group_id": 42443967,
        "user_fields": {
            "system::embeddable_last_seen": "2017-06-21T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code it will work for you:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="jput.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   


        $("#users").jPut({
            ajax_url:"my.json",  //if you want to call from a json file
            name:"users",
        });

});
</script> 
<div jput="users">
        <table border="1">
            <td>Id: {{id}}</td>
            <td>Id: {{email}}</td>
        </table>
</div>
<div id="users"></div>
```

Comment: hi @Harsh Patel, 
sure

Comment: Check in console you are getting error like cross origin.right??

Comment: nope still the same error on my screenshot
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: @ivor please check my edited answer it will work for you

Comment: Thanks man, this time the error is:
"ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: Have you changed your file name?? Or you can check response by console.log(data); before var userData=data.user; let me know what you recevice in response

Comment: I think miss something, my browser didn't load my json file... but now its working on the console... i can see my id and email address...

how can i display it on the html?

by the way man thanks

Comment: @ivor check my edited code It will useful for convert json to html

Comment: You need to pass valid json for this and must add dataName:"user",  option in   
       $("#users").jPut({ 
            dataName:"user", 
            ajax_url:"my.json", 
            name:"users",
        });

Comment: Please note you need to pass valid JSON as per current reference we need to pass like { user: [{id:1},{id:2}] } use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to validate json